# Yii2 two submitt button with two link

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to create two submit button in one form that have two action. I try  with below code.problem is even it shows the required link when we inspect but when I click on Save & finalized button it redirect to the create in this form action is create link.

**form**

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id'=>'reset-password',
            // 'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'options' => [ 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]);
         ?>
  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'category')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label('Category') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'rough_or_cut')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label('Type') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'cut')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label('Cut') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'shape')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label('Shape') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
   <div class="form-group">               
                <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-success save']) ?>
                <?= Html::a('Save & Finalize',['production-order-items/finalize','id'=> $model->isNewRecord ? null: $model->id,], [
                    'data' =>[
                        'method' => 'post',
                        'params' => [
                        ],
                    ],
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary saveAndFinalize'
                ]) ?>
            </div>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

what the problem with this code?. and is there any way to do this in yii2?.

Answer (score 0):

1. solution: Use JavaScript (jquery).  Create two links (or buttons - not submitButtons). In .js file bind onClick event on each button (link) which call different function. In this function set your form attribute 'action' with corresponding action a submit them. The same for second function but different 'action'.
2. solution: This solution post form to only one action. But in action you can check which button was submitted through it's name. Instead `Html::submitButton()` use `Html::submitInput()` with different 'name' attribute and then in action check if `!is_null(\Yii::$app->request->post('first_submit_input_name'))` ...